# Difference of comma and semicolon when assign values in one line in python

Tags: python

I am writing if statement in Python and I need to assign multiple values.

In order to style it, I want all my assignment in one line. So I tried comma to separate them.

```
if True:
    a=0.5, b=0.5
    print(a), print(b)
```

This would have a syntax error:

`SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`

However, when I use semicolon it works.

```
if True:
    a=0.5; b=0.5
    print(a), print(b)
```

Why can comma work in `print` but not in assignment?

Comment: Change `a=0.5, b=0.5` to `a, b = 0.5, 0.5`. As for the `;`, it marks the end of a statement. So `a=0.5;` is one statement that is separate from `b=0.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas in Python are used for things like function arguments and creating tuples and lists. If you notice the command-line output when running this

```
>>> print(a), print(b)
0.5
0.5
(None, None)
```

the `(None, None)` is the resulting tuple created from the output value of two print statements put together with a comma. `None, None` is the same as `(None, None)`.

The printed `0.5` values are the so-called *side-effect* of the `print` statement. It is what ends up on your screen when printing -- but the return value of a print is actually `None`.

Also notice the effect of

```
>>> a=0.5, 0.6
>>> print(a)
(0.5, 0.6)
```

`a` is assigned both of the two values following the equal sign since there is a comma. And now we are getting closer to the solution, these two statements are identical:

```
a=0.5, b=0.5
a = (0.5, b) = 0.5
```

so Python attempts to assign the last `0.5` to the value of the previous statement, which it can't. Basically doing a literal assignment giving a syntax error:

```
>>> (0.6, 0.7) = 0.5
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, commas in python are used to unpack tuples. When you use a comma in a `print` function, you're actually using two [tuples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm). Semicolons are used as a separator, as they would be used in a language such as JS or C++, and are equivalent to a newline. A literal is essentially the opposite of a variable; a constant or fixed value.

If you want to do two assignments in one line, what you can do is; `a, b = 0.5, 0.5`

However, in your case, you can assign variables as such; `a = b = 0.5`